# Get weekend using Moment

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm working on a date and I got stuck on this task. So is it possible to get weekend in array of date using Moment instead of `getDay()`? I'm new in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are *actually* trying to do?  What does "get weekend in array of date" mean?  You have an array of dates and you want to see which ones are sat/sun? or you want to see when the weekend starts or ends in relation to your dates?  it's not really clear what your need is here.

Comment: @Claies the first one, I need to get all weekend in array of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library of 'business' utilities for moment, called moment-business, at https://github.com/jmeas/moment-business, which has a isWeekendDay(moment) method.

So, you could filter your array, checking each date to see if it is a weekendDay.

For example, if you have an array of moment objects, you could do:

```
myArray.filter((m) => business.isWeekendDay(m));
```

or, if you have an array of Dates, you could do

```
myArray.filter((d) => business.isWeekendDay(moment(d));
```

A warning, though - the isWeekendDay method is documented as returning: "Whether or not the Moment occurs on Saturday or Sunday."

If that's ok for all locales that you will be operating in, that's fine, but you'll want to check to be sure that you won't be operating in a local where that's not the definition of a weekend day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using standard moment functionality by creating simple function:

```
function isWeekend(date: string): number {
return parseInt(moment(date).format('E'),0) > 5
}
```

`format('E')` will return sequence number day of the week.